# CakePHP 3: Properly writing functions for the Entity Model

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller

I have a blog model, and I suspect I'm not writing my code correctly to best take advantage of CakePHP's MVC structure.

Here are some snippets from my Posts controller.

```
public function view() {
    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all')->contain([
        'Comments' => ['Users'],
        'Users'
    ]);
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}

public function index() {
    $post = $this->Posts->find('all')->contain([
        'Users'
    ])->limit(20);
    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

This is a snippet from the `index.ctp` template

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    <div class="post">
        <h1 class="title>
            <?= h($post->title) ?>
            <small><?php echo $post->getCommentCount(); ?> comments</small>
        </h1>
        <div class="body">
            <?= h($post->body) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

In my Post Entity, I have the following function

```
public function getCommentCount(){
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($this->comments as $comment){
        if ( $comment->isPublished() ) {
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

My problem is I need to call the `getCommentCount` function from the `index.ctp` where the `$posts` object has no `comment` children (which the function uses).

Am I misunderstanding how the Entity functions should be coded? Instead of accessing *expected* variables of this object which sometimes aren't there, should I be querying the database from the Entity? Is there another approach I should be doing?

Comment: Add your index.ctp snippet showing the call of getCommentCount()

Comment: @RayannNayran done!

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: @RayannNayran `Invalid arguments supplied for foreach` in the Entity class. Which makes sense, because in this instance there isn't any `comments` supplied in the `post` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding how the Entity functions should be coded?

Yes, you do, because...

> Instead of accessing expected variables of this object which sometimes aren't there, should I be querying the database from the Entity? Is there another approach I should be doing?

...an entity should be a dumb data object. When you fetch data from there you add business logic. Any data manipulation should happen somewhere in the model layer, or a service. Most of the time people using CakePHP put code into the table object, which is somewhat OKish. I'm creating additional classes in the model layer for different things and namespace them `App\Model\SomeModule` or directly in my app root `App\SomeModule` and inject whatever else I need there (request, tables...).

This code is also absolute inefficient:

```
public function getCommentCount(){
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($this->comments as $comment){
        if ( $comment->isPublished() ) {
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

- It assumes **all** comments were loaded
- It is *required* to get **all** comments to get an accurate count
- it iterates over **all** comments to filter published comments
- It does it inside the entity

What if there are 500 comments? Why aren't you simply doing a count query on the database and filter them by their published status? But this would still require you to do one additional query per record. So for counts it is a lot more efficient and easy if you use the [Counter Cache Behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html).

If you *really* need to manipulate data after you fetched it but before rendering it use [map/reduce](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce). You can refactor your getCommentCount() and use map/reduce instead if you would like to stick to your inefficient way of doing it. The linked documentation even contains an example for counting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In your index funcition you set `$post`, but in the `index.ctp` you use `$posts`, and you missed out to contain `Comments` relationship in your query.

I changed it for you:

```
public function index() {
    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all')->contain([
        'Users',
        'Comments'
    ])
    ->limit(20);

    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

And based on your comment, you could get the total comments in a query like this:

```
public function index() {
    $posts = $this->Posts->find();
    $posts->select([
        'total_comments' => $posts->func()->sum('Comments.id')
    ])
    ->select($this->Posts)
    ->contain([
        'Users',
        'Comments'
    ])
    ->limit(20);

    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

See [Returning the Total Count of Records](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records) for more info.

Comment: So, syntactically that fixes my problem and makes the bug go away. However I do want to get the counts on the `index.ctp`. I was unsure if function in the Entity class should be implemented this way, or if I should be querying the database instead.
I would rather not have all comments in all posts in the index, just to get the counts because that seems like a rather data intensive query. I was hoping there would be another way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find('all' , [
        'fields' => array_merge(
                $this->Posts->schema()->columns(), [
                    'countCommentsAlias' => '(
                        SELECT COUNT(comments.id) 
                        FROM comments 
                        WHERE comments.post_id = Posts.id
                    )', 
                    'Users.name', 
                    'Users.email'
                ]
            ), 

        'contain' => ['Users']   
    ])
->toArray();
```